# Azure DevOps Nginx Deployment error for K8s 1.24.x

Tags: nginx-ingress

I was trying to deploy nginx ingress controller in AKS using yaml. While deploying I'm getting below error:

`unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "icat-backend-ingress" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"`

I tried to change the yaml as per the docs but it is still failing.

Here is the sample yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xxxxxxxxx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    # {{- if .Values.service.resourceGroup }}
    # {{- range $key, $value := .Values.service.resourceGroup }}
    # {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    # {{- end }}
    # {{- end }}    
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/keepalive: "600"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 30m
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: 30m
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.ingressUrl }}
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingressUrl }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: "Prefix"
        backend:
          service:
            name: xxxxxxxx
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /(api.*)
        pathType: "Prefix"
        backend:
          service:
            name: xxxxxxx
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete any old releases and redeploy

Your build is still referencing manifests from old releases hence it’s failing because those api’s are deprecated.
So one you delete the old releases from past builds and redeploy it should go through